# Duplicate assets path name when loading a local html file

Tags: react-native, webview, assets, expo

I'm trying to load a local html file from my assets folder

```
const localUri = Expo.Asset.fromModule(
  require('../../../assets/intercom/intercom.html'),
);
```

the file got loaded, but the problem comes when an addition assets path got added to the localUri.uri path

here's an example of the output of localUri.uri 
 "html",
`"uri": "http://192.168.1.113:19001/assets/assets/intercom/intercom.html?platform=android&hash=b7f8ed17a6eb37cb8609261ed66e4843?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false"`

rather it should be (without duplicate assets)
`"uri": "http://192.168.1.113:19001/assets/intercom/intercom.html?platform=android&hash=b7f8ed17a6eb37cb8609261ed66e4843?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false"`

Comment: You want to save multiple uri?

Comment: no @hongdevelop, i only need to load that file, and when i'm loading it i got the duplicate assets path

Comment: I may not be able to understand you because my English is not good enough, but do you mean that the path overlaps when loading other html files?

Comment: correct, i got two assets paths '/assets/assets', it should only be one 'assets' not two

Comment: Can you try this? `Expo.Asset.fromModule(
  require('../../../assets/analytics/analytics.html').uri`

Comment: no i got the above content in uri: "uri": "http://192.168.1.113:19001/assets/assets/intercom/i...." @hongdevelop

Comment: oh i'm misstake `Expo.Asset.fromModule( require('../../../assets/analytics/analytics.html')).uri`

Comment: yeah i've got "uri": "http://192.168.1.113:19001/assets/assets/intercom/intercom.html?platform=android&hash=b7f8ed17a6eb37cb8609261ed66e4843?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false" with duplicate assets

Comment: or `Expo.Asset.fromModule( require('../../../assets/analytics/analytics.html')). localUri`

Comment: for localUri i got null

Comment: I brought only one price when I tried this equally. `Expo.Asset.fromModule( require('../../../assets/analytics/analytics.html')).uri`

Comment: `localUri's have one value` // my same code

Comment: which environment are you working on ios or android?

Comment: I am simply a project made through Expo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195453/discussion-between-m1m6-and-hong-develop).